# Charset Problem with youtube Gdata

Tags: php, xml

i have a few problems with multi language support.

My website is using charset iso 8859 1

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

When i the fetched title or content is in chinese, the display will be funky text

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
if (@$doc->load($url) === false) return;
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$content = $doc->getElementsByTagName("content")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

However if i change my header to UTF-8, it will work, however due to other scripts i wont be able to do that. any idea how?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `utf8_decode()` will do:

```
  $title = utf8_decode($title);
  $content= utf8_decode($content);
```

For more complex conversions from one character set to another, one would usually use [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

e.g.

```
 $title = iconv("UTF-8", "iso-8859-1", $title);
 $content = iconv("UTF-8", "iso-8859-1", $content);
```

Comment: Notice: Iconv() [Function.Iconv]: Detected An Illegal Character In Input String

Comment: @damian then your incoming data is probably not UTF-8. Check what encoding the remote URL specifies

Comment: @damian chinese characters can't be displayed in ISO-8859-1. They're outside its range. You'll need to use UTF-8 on your output page

Comment: that's sad. Can you give me 5mins so i can ask you another question if i were to set UTF-8 as the primary.

Comment: @damian that may be worth a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Chinese characters won't display correct if your web page charset is iso-8859-1
pick UTF-8 or gb2312, big5 
then convert it using `mb_convert_encoding`

```
mb_detect_order(array('utf-8', 'big5', 'gb2312'));
$in_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($str);
if (!$in_encoding || $in_encoding=='EUC-CN' || $in_encoding=='BIG-5') 
{
  $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
}
```